# How to Ignore Media and Static URLS in Django Middleware

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to redirect users who don't have permission to see that page. In my database i have saved url names . Example - `company_list`

```
path('company/list', CompanyListView.as_view(), name='company_list'),
```

Now i am using EXEMPT_URLS where url names are saved and user is exempted for those urls.

```
EXEMPT_URLS = [
    'login',
    'logout',
    'superadmin_dashboard',
    'admin_dashboard',
]

class PermissionRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

        print(request.path_info)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and current_url not in EXEMPT_URLS :
           if request.user.userprofile.user_role_id == 1:
                return redirect('superadmin_dashboard')
            else:
                return redirect('admin_dashboard')
```

Now the problem come here. Like i am adding a company and its logo. and when i m going to `company_list` it is showing me the list but not images.

`"GET /media/user_profiles/logo_L7T5FKg.png HTTP/1.1" 302`

I founded the problem, when i commented `def process_view()` it is showing me images in my template. But when i uncomment it it does not showing images. Basically my middleware is blocking that `"GET /media/user_profiles/logo_L7T5FKg.png HTTP/1.1" 302`.

How can i that image url name and put in `EXEMPT_URLS`

Answer (score 0):

Basically i was redirecting to dashboard if the user don't have permission. So in my middleware `MEDIA and STATIC URL` was getting the `HTTP response status code 302 Found` because for `MEDIA AND STATIC URL` my custom middleware was also running. So to ignore i found `request.path`.

```
from django.conf import settings
    ...

    MEDIA_URL = request.path.startswith(settings.MEDIA_URL)
    STATIC_URL = request.path.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and current_url not in EXEMPT_URLS and not MEDIA_URL and not STATIC_URL:
        if request.user.userprofile.user_role_id == 1:
            return redirect('superadmin_dashboard')
        else:
            return redirect('admin_dashboard')
```

Comment: Do you have any different approach?

Comment: uhu, I misread your code, sorry - the fact you used the same names as the one in settings fooled me. Your test is actually ok (technically at least), you may just want to 1/ use less misleading names (ie "is_media_url" and "is_static_url") and 2/ test those before the `not in EXEMPT_URLS` (a boolean test is faster than a containment test on a list).

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the request is comming from static or media url and do nothing if so like this

```
EXEMPT_URLS = [
    'login',
    'logout',
    'superadmin_dashboard',
    'admin_dashboard',
]

class PermissionRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # Skip middleware for media and static files requests
        if request.path.startswith(settings.MEDIA_URL) or request.path.startswith(settings.STATIC_URL):
            return None
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

        print(request.path_info)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and current_url not in EXEMPT_URLS :
            if request.user.userprofile.user_role_id == 1:
                return redirect('superadmin_dashboard')
            else:
                return redirect('admin_dashboard')
```